# regarding array declaration in c++

Tags: c++

```
int main(){

        int n;

        scanf("%d",&n);

        int a[n];
}
```

In the above where does the space for array a[] , get allocated ? In stack or heap ?

Comment: OT: Variable length arrays aren't allowed in standard C++. What compiler? What operating system?

Comment: I am asking a general question regarding memory allocation , not specifically about very large arrays

Comment: @jaig it's not valid C++ code (although it is valid C), so it gives you a compiler error and doesn't get allocated anywhere (some compilers allow this as an extension, but it's not standard C++)

Comment: @PeterT Diagnostics are implementation-specific, and a compiler (neither GCC or Clang by default) doesn't have to give a fatal error. So the question still has a valid answer.

Comment: but this program runs well in ideone and also on my pc which has standard gcc compiler , I run this as a .cpp file

Comment: @jaig and that doesn't change the fact it's invalid.

Comment: My problem is: 1. We know that a compiler allocates memory statically during compilation ( the memory size on stack will be decided by the size of the array 'n'- which is however not known at that time )

Comment: 2. Memory allocation is not on heap as we not using new keyword

Comment: 1 and 2 implies neither in heap nor in stack , then where?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz it seems to be valid C, even if it looks very strange at first glance.

Comment: @Wolf And the question is tagged C++.

Comment: @Bartek , your justification does not satisfy me

Comment: @jaig that's too bad, then. [read about VLAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) in the meantime.

Comment: @jaig: Compile with the option `-pedantic-errors` in order to enforce strict language conformance.

Comment: Downvoters: please explain! The question seems absurd only at first glance.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley  `-std=c++11` or similar would be more effective. `-pedantic` only catches the puristic things.

Comment: Shouldn't there be new scope for the declaration of `a` in C?

Comment: Its a pity to see a question receive negative votes ... People ask question or doubt when they are not clear about a topic , the questioin may seem irrelevant to few people but it would clear up the doubts of many people new in this field ... shame to u guys who down voted this question ..

Comment: @rubenvb: More effective in what? I'm talking about catching non-standard extensions (such as VLAs). `-std=c++11` will not do that.

Comment: @Benjamin wow, that sucks indeed. `-pedantic` it is. The standard option should give an error IMHO.

Comment: @jaig I think some comments in your code could make it easier to understand your actual question. Most people (including myself) don't realize the array definition in this place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable length arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

If your compiler compiles that, it's most likely going to be on the stack. In standard parlance, if you care to apply that to a construct that's not actually standard-conforming, it has automatic storage duration, meaning you don't have to clean it up yourself and it will become invalid at the end of the scope.

What you have there is a VLA (variable length array), a construct from C that allows you to have arrays whose dimensions are known only at runtime. Usually, the way they work is similar to the "function" `alloca`, which decreases the stack pointer by an amount known at runtime and "returns" the pointer to it. I put "function" in quotes because doing this requires some low-level hackery that's not provided for by normal function scope semantics.

VLAs don't exist in C++, so you're using a compiler extension, and the precise semantics of VLAs in that extension depend on your compiler. Since this is likely gcc, I'll leave you a link to [the relevant part of its documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

Comment: if on stack , how much memory will a compiler allocate without knowing its size?

Comment: The stack size remains fixed. If your VLA would be larger than the space left on stack, you get a stack overflow. The problem is roughly equivalent to a runaway recursive function that requires more and more stack space until it is exhausted -- the size there is also not known at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

In the C11 standard, it describes in §6.7.6.2/4 what actually makes an array a variable length array:

> If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has
>   a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array
>   type; otherwise, the array type is a *variable length array* type.

Yet in [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (C++11 draft), [dcl.array] says:

> If the *constant-expression* (5.19) is present, it shall be an
>   integral constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero.

The language about "variable length array"s are completely missing, so they don't exist in C++.

The draft talks about object lifetime in [basic.life]. In C, VLAs cannot have static or thread storage duration. §6.2.4/7 then says:

> For such an object that does have a variable length array type, its
>   lifetime extends from the declaration of the object until execution of
>   the program leaves the scope of the declaration.<sup>35)</sup> If the
>   scope is entered recursively, a new instance of the object is created
>   each time. The initial value of the object is indeterminate.

GCC, which allows VLAs in C++ as an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html), mimics the same semantics:

> Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and as an
>   extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++. These arrays are
>   declared like any other automatic arrays, but with a length that is
>   not a constant expression. The storage is allocated at the point of
>   declaration and deallocated when the block scope containing the
>   declaration exits.

Clang also allows VLAs for compatibility with some [restrictions](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla).

So more than likely, VLAs are allocated on the stack.

Comment: "Secondly, the "heap" and "stack" are misnomers" - not really. Dynamic objects come from a "free store", which is just another name for a "heap". Automatic storage behaves like a stack, so we might as well call it a "stack" (as the C++ standard does in various places).

Comment: @MikeSeymour So, it's allocated on a stack on the heap?

Comment: @Wolf VLAs have automatic storage duration like the other answer says.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler must know what is the size of all array int the code before execute the project.
You cant assign it while the program runs.

Comment: This argument is outdated. The question is about variable-length arrays, a relatively new feature in C (and an extension in some C++ compilers).